# After reset fields with .val(''), the form fields are empty until the page will be reloaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my document I use Bootstrap Modal to load a document dynamically. In this Modal Window I use ajax to add the value of two form fields to the database. After the successfully request I reset the two form filed with .val(''). This works fine but when I'm close the Modal window and open It again, every time the form field are empty. Only when I'm reload the page and open the Modal, all works fine.

Where is the error? The reset of the two form field is for the whole session until I'm reload the page.

Here is my ajax code:

```
        $(document).on('click', 'form.form-inline button', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var pMacaddr = $('#macaddr').val();
        var pHostname = $('#hostname').val();

        var that = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: propertie.backend+'?action=ajax&method=addmac&lang='+propertie.language+'&code='+Math.random(),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'hostname': pHostname,
                'macaddr': pMacaddr,
            },error: function(data) {
                alert('PHP-Error: '+data['responseText']);
            },success: function(data) {
                if (data.success === false) {
                    alert(data.message);
                } else {

                    var html = "<tr id=\""+pId+"\">\n";
                        html += "\t<td>"+pMacaddr+"</td>\n";
                        html += "\t<td>"+pHostname+"</td>\n";
                        html += "\t<td><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" title=\""+propertie.l10n.delete+"\">";
                        html += "<i class=\"fa fa-close fa-fw\"></i></a><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\"";
                        html += " title=\""+propertie.l10n.edit+"\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil fa-fw\"></i></a></td>\n</tr>\n";

                        $(that).closest("tr").before(html);

                        $('#macaddr').val('');
                        $('#hostname').val('');

                }
            },cache: false,
        });

    });
```

To open the Modal I use this code:

```
        $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]', function(e) {
        $('#ajaxModal').removeData('bs.modal');
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        var $this = $(this)
        , $remote = $this.data('remote') || $this.attr('href')
        , $modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"></div></div></div>');
        $('body').append($modal);
        $modal.modal({remote: $remote});
        $modal.modal('show');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. The Modal element was only hidden, not removed from the document. I have modify my Open-Modal function and now the Modal window will be removed from the document when I close the Modal.

```
        // open modal
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var $this = $(this)
        , $id = $this.data('id') || 'ajaxModal'
        , $remote = $this.data('remote') || $this.attr('href')
        , $modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="'+$id+'" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"></div></div></div>');

        $('body').append($modal);
        $modal.modal({remote: $remote, keyboard: false, backdrop: false});
        $modal.modal('show');

        // On hidden event, remove the current modal from document
        $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#'+$id, function(e) {
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });
```

And now the form fields works with val().